# Do not-to-screen stdout and stderr take resources?

Tags: linux, stdout, stderr, dev-null

I have a Python program, it has lots of "print" statements that print stuff to output constantly.

If I run the script using "nohup", and do not redirect the output to "/dev/null". After a long-time running, will be "hidden" output, which not shown on screen, take resources away?

Comment: Well, generally No. It's not `stdin, stdout, stderr` taking resources away. The most probable issue you are dealing with is lines of "scrollback" in your terminal. Some terminals allow an "unlimited" scrollback. In that case you can literally have millions of lines of code buffered. Setting a sane value for the lines of scrollback kept (up to you but 100K should be enough) should help fix that problem. `stdin, stdout, stderr` do have small read/write buffers associated with the stream itself (generally between .5 and 8k depending on OS), but that is simply for I/O buffering.